# Font Family isn't working for Outlook Signature

Tags: email, outlook

I have the problem that the Outlook Signature neither Font Face nor the 2 or 3 font is adopted. Responsive design (IOS) always uses the standard font. Have tried other fonts but unfortunately not. Desktop is working very well but on Iphone it isn't

Outlook 2007 / 2010

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <style type="text/css">
   @font-face {
   font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   src: local('Tw Cen MT'), url('Tw Cen MT.woff') format('woff');
   }
         body, table.body, body.table, table td, a {
         font-family: Tw Cen MT, Calibri, sans-serif;
         text-decoration:none !important;
   color: #000;
         }
         .images {
         display:inherit;
         width:50px;
         float:left;
         }
         a {
         color: #0d0d0d;
         font-size: 13.0pt;
         }
         a:visited {
         color: #000 !important;
         text-decoration:none !important;
         }
         span.MsoHyperlink {
         mso-style-priority:99;
         color:inherit;
         }
         span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
         mso-style-priority:99;
         color:inherit;
         } 
  </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <table width="600">
  <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="10" style="font-family: Tw Cen MT, Calibri, sans-serif;">
     <p style=""><strong>Mit freundlichen Grüßen / Kind regards</strong></p>
     <p style=""><strong>xxxxx</strong><br>Founder &amp; President</p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
      <table style="color: #0d0d0d;font-size: 13.0pt;" width="600">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="10">
                  <img src="logo_klein_first_class.jpg">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="10" style="font-family: Tw Cen MT, Calibri, sans-serif;">
                  <p>Corporate Headquarters</p>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="10" style="font-family: Tw Cen MT, Calibri, sans-serif;">
                  <p><strong style="font-size: 17.0pt;">Text</strong></p>
               </td>
            </tr>
         
            <tr>
               <td colspan="10">
                  <table cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody cellspacing="0"><tr style="line-height: 90%;mso-line-height: taro-papo;">
                        <td style="font-family: Tw Cen MT, Calibri, sans-serif;">
                           <p style="line-height: 10px;">
                              <a href="https://www.google.at/search?source=hp&amp;ei=eutrXOfPC4fNwAKtqqOAAg&amp;q=D%C3%B6rrstra%C3%9Fe+85&amp;btnK=Google-Suche&amp;oq=D%C3%B6rrstra%C3%9Fe+85&amp;gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j38j0i22i30.1068684.1068684..1069327...0.0..0.200.200.2-1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....0.wMhkS1hD0ig">
                              xxxxx x</a>
                           </p>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right:20px; font-size:20px;font-family: Tw Cen MT, Calibri, sans-serif;">
                           <p><strong>I</strong></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <p>x x / x</p>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr style="line-height: 90%;mso-line-height: taro-papo;">
                        <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                           <p><strong>x: </strong>+43 124565</p>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right:20px; font-size:20px;">
                           <p><strong>I</strong></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <p><strong>Fax:</strong> +43 1215</p>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr style="line-height: 90%;mso-line-height: taro-papo;">
                        <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                           <p><strong>Email: </strong><a style="color: #0d0d0d;font-size: 13.0pt;" href="mailto:">xxxx.com</a></p>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right:20px; font-size:20px;">
                           <p><strong>I</strong></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <p><strong>Homepage:</strong> <a style="color: #0d0d0d;font-size: 13.0pt;" href="xxx.com">www.xxx-xxx.com</a></p>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody></table>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="10" height="5">
                  
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="10" style="font-family: Tw Cen MT, Calibri, sans-serif;">
                  <strong>Folgen Sie uns auf:</strong>
               </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
               <td colspan="1" width="75">
                  <p class="images">
                     <a title="Text Linkedin" href="" target="_blank">
                     <img src="linkedin.png" alt="" style="" width="40" height="40"></a>
                  </p>
               </td>
               <td colspan="1" width="75">
                  <p class="images"><a title="Text Xing" href="https://" target="_blank">
                     <img src="xing.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
                  </p>
               </td>
               <td colspan="1" width="85">
                  <p class="images"> <a title="Text Google Plus" href="https" target="_blank" style="">
                     <img src="googleplus.png" alt="" style="" width="62" height="62"></a>
                  </p>
               </td>
               <td colspan="1" width="75">
                  <p class="images"><a title="Text Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" style="">
                     <img src="facebook.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
                  </p>
               </td>
      
      <td colspan="1" width="75">
                  <p class="images"><a title="Text Twitter" href="https://twitter.c" target="_blank" style="">
                     <img src="twitter-logo-silhouette.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
                  </p>
               </td>
               <td colspan="1" width="75">
                  <p class="images"><a title="" href="" target="_blank" style="">
                     <img src="gemconnect.jpg" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
                  </p>
               </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="10">  
    </td>
   </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   <table width="800">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="10" style="font-family: Tw Cen MT, Calibri, sans-serif;">
                  <p>Text  </p>
               </td>
            </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
   
 </body>
</html>
```

I also tried google webfont. but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007-2019 only really supports websafe fonts. It doesn't work with webfonts like Google Fonts. Gmail also lacks webfont support.

You can set up a primary font from a list of fonts supported by Outlook which includes Arial, Arial Black, Comic Sans, Courier New, Georgia, Impact, Charcoal, Lucida Console, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, Tahoma, Geneva, Times, Times New Roman, Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Monaco.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/ttf/
- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/d23s80po/

Good luck.

```
*To include a link to a full list of supported Outlook fonts, I have to do this.
```